# Output Path for Shared T4 Template

Tags: visual-studio, t4

How can I specify the output path of a T4 template?

When I add my T4 template using "Add as Link" to my project from `$TemplatePath$`, it generates the output file in `$TemplatePath$`, not `$ProjectPath$`. How can I specify that `$ProjectPath` is where the generated file is placed?

Comment: I got around this by having a master template in one location and then templates that imported that one (but did little else) in each project. Of course, that's not the nicest solution so I'm interested to see if anyone can solve this.

Comment: @Jeff Yates - please add this as an answer!

Comment: Jeff - I would say that is actually a very nice solution.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks. I thought I was just being lazy when I used it for different web.config's based on build configuration - it was my first time using T4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got around this by having a master template in one location and then templates that imported that one (but did little else) in each project. Of course, that's not the nicest solution.

Comment: Posted as an answer as requested.

Comment: Do you have any examples of how to do this?

Comment: @Jimmy When creating a stub .tt file, you can include the main one with this directive: 
`<#@ include file="..\SomeProject\OriginalTemplateFile.tt" #>`

Answer (score 1):

We typically use the same system that Jeff Yates mentioned with minimal (often single line) stub templates including the shared template.

You could also use Oleg Sych's T4Toolbox to project output to any directory you please.

However, the standard IVsSingleFileGenerator that T4's custom tool is built upon doesn't have any dials to turn to control it's output location and it's behavior in the case of linked files is as you describe.